# Why the animation is different when animation code is in keyboard show method?

Tags: ios, animation, uikeyboard

I want to add an animation when keyboard is showing, I try to add animation like this

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
   _inputTextView.center = CGPointMake(300, 500);

   [UIView animateWithDuration:4 animations:^{
      _inputTextView.center = CGPointMake(300, 100);
   } completion:nil];
}
```

before animation I try to set textView center to (300, 500), but it seems not work.
[image]

**If I move the code to button click method it works as I want**, it just like the system has changed my animation when in keyboard method, anyone know the reason and tell me why? thanks!
[image]

Comment: try this line _inputTextView.center = CGPointMake(300, 500); in - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField Delegate Method.

Comment: @GOPALVASANI It works, but the animation duration is the same as the keyboard up duration, it seems my view animation code in keyboard method will be ignored but the system add animation itself, I want to know why system did this..

Comment: system will call first textField's Delegate Method and after that it will call keyboardWillAppear Notification Method , so your animation code not ignored here . And what you want exactlly ?

Comment: @GOPALVASANI I want my animation code to work properly just like in other methods.

Comment: @GOPALVASANI If I put _inputTextView.center = CGPointMake(300, 500); to textFieldDidBeginEditing and keep animation in keyboardWillAppear the animation duration is not 4.0, and even I don't add animation in  keyboardWillAppear it also has an animation..

Comment: animation occured because of delegate method , you tell the compiler that animate the _inputTextView.center while textField starts to begin editing.

Comment: your question is not clear , without that i can't help you.

Comment: @GOPALVASANI If I put all code to textFieldDidBeginEditing it works as I wanted, I want to know why the keyboard delegate add an animation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159638/discussion-between-cajsaiko-and-gopal-vasani).